# Biq query...Cost implication on flattening data

Tags: google-bigquery

How much time it takes in fattening query?

I believe, flattening happens at run time, so would that make query response time slower?

Answer (score 1):

- The cost of a query is calculated based on the size of the columns that you read. You can read more in the [documentation on pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).
- Yes, flattening has a (generally negligible) overhead for legacy SQL. Just use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) and then this isn't an issue, though.